# Resize characters in figure caption

Tags: math-mode, floats, captions, fontsize

I frequently use `\scalebox` from the `graphics` package in math-environment as
$x^{ \scalebox{0.55}{(n)} }_{i}$
which works fine.

However, I am not able to use the same sequence in a figure caption:

```
\begin{figure}
  test
  \caption{test $x^{ \scalebox{0.55}{(n)} }_{i}$}
\end{figure}
```

The error message follows:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
&lt;inserted text&gt; 
                 \par 
l.20 ...ion{test $x^{ \scalebox{0.55}{(n)} }_{i}$}

Runaway argument?
\@captype {\Gscale@box {0.55}}\def \reserved@b {\Gscale@box {0.55}[0.\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
\&lt;to be read again&gt; 
                    \par 
l.20 ...ion{test $x^{ \scalebox{0.55}{(n)} }_{i}$}
```

Same errors appear when `\scalebox` is used outside the math environment in standard text.

Is there an alternative to resize parts of the caption text, in particular in the math environment?

%% ---------- Edit: Solution in minimal example ----------------------

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article} % usually I am working with IEEEtran
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

$x^{ \scalebox{0.55}{$(n)$} }_{i}$ % in standard text


\begin{figure}  % using \protect as suggested by Herbert
  test
  \caption{test $x^{ \protect\scalebox{0.55}{$(n)$} }_{i}$}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}   % without \scalebox as suggested by egreg and tohecz
   test
   \caption{test $x^{ \scriptscriptstyle(\!n\!) }_{i}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As well, please let us know what exactly is your goal. Using `\scalebox` to resize a letter is a very wrong way.

Comment: Why not simply `$x^{\scriptscriptstyle(n)}$`?

Comment: Thanks! As suggested I will avoid \scalebox . The \scriptscriptstyle works fine. In the edited version of the question I added the suggested solutions.

Comment: apart from scaling text almost always being the wrong thing to do `\scalebox` here gives you the _wrong font_ it is like `\mbox` and gives you a text font `n` not a math font. Also _why_ don't you want the standard scriptsize ?

Comment: Yes, in my initial post I forgot to mention the $ characters in the \scalebox.
The reason for not using the standard scriptsize are the different line spacings when superscripts are used- which looks awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe `\protect`

```
\caption{test $x^{\protect\scalebox{0.55}{(n)} }_{i}$}
```

Comment: @ubere It avoids the error and does what you intended (so Herbert deserves the tick:-) but it is always the wrong thing to do, as noted in comments on the question.